creating tron network address using public key
i want to create an address using already created public key
my public key is : 02b5db198c55d70a70a076ef9666e91ee2db7988dd488430e3f0c2907971ba6fb7
and address should be :TBWPs4wQw8f2TshH5bcV4andP95WhTEwvb
but when i use my code to create address for this public key the result is wrong , i dont know why and i think my code is okey,but it just does not work. so i decide to share the code with you :
 static string GenerateTronAddress(string publicKey)
{
    // Step 1: Perform Keccak-256 hash on the public key
    var publicKeyBytes = HexToByteArray(publicKey);
    var hashedPublicKey = ComputeKeccak256(publicKeyBytes);
    
    // Step 2: Take the last 20 bytes of the hashed public key
    var addressBytes = new byte[21];
    addressBytes[0] = 0x41; // TRON network prefix
    var last20byte = hashedPublicKey[(hashedPublicKey.Length - 20)..];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 20; i++)
    {
        addressBytes[i+1] = last20byte[i];
    }
    var twiceHashedAddress = GetSHA256(GetSHA256(addressBytes));
    var verificationCode = twiceHashedAddress[0..4]; 
     var finalAddressBytes = new byte[25];
    Array.Copy(addressBytes ,0 , finalAddressBytes , 0 ,addressBytes.Length );
    Array.Copy(verificationCode , 0 , finalAddressBytes , addressBytes.Length , verificationCode.Length );

    // Step 3: Convert the address to Base58Check format
    var addressBase58 = Encoders.Base58Check.EncodeData(finalAddressBytes);
    return addressBase58;
}
static byte[] ComputeKeccak256(byte[] input)
{
    using (var sha3 = Sha3.Sha3256())
    {
        return sha3.ComputeHash(input);
    }
}

 static byte[] HexToByteArray(string hex)
{
    if (hex.Length % 2 != 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Hex string must have an even length");

    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
 static byte[] GetSHA256(byte[] data)
{
    var inputHash = SHA256.HashData(data);
    return inputHash;
}

i should mention : code language is c#
